How do I properly use react-hook-form for a custom component where the value is set by a button click?
I'm trying to create a custom Date Picker component. The component will contain a button that is visible to the user and when clicked, it will set the current date as a string in an input field. I'm using react-hook-form for this.
This is my DatePicker component:
import {
  useState,
  forwardRef,
  useRef,
  useImperativeHandle,
  PropsWithChildren,
} from "react";
import { format } from "date-fns";

interface DatePickerProps extends PropsWithChildren {
  error?: string;
}

const DatePicker = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, DatePickerProps>(
  ({ error, ...props }, forwardedRef) => {
    const [date, setDate] = useState<Date>();

    const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    useImperativeHandle(forwardedRef, () => ref.current as HTMLInputElement);

    const dateString = date?.toISOString() ?? "";

    const handleDateSelect = () => {
      const date: Date = new Date();
      setDate(date);
    };

    return (
      <>
        <p>Date: {date && format(date, "MMMM dd")}</p>
        <p>
          <input
            ref={ref}
            {...props}
            value={dateString}
            className={error ? "error" : undefined}
          />
          <button type="button" onClick={handleDateSelect}>
            Set Date
          </button>
        </p>
      </>
    );
  }
);

export default DatePicker;


The parent component, holding the form:
import "./styles.css";
import { SubmitHandler, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import DatePicker from "./datepicker";

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<{ date: string | undefined }>({
    defaultValues: {
      date: undefined,
    },
  });

  const onSave: SubmitHandler<{ date: string | undefined }> = async (data) => {
    console.log("Validated form data:");
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSave)}>
        <DatePicker
          error={errors.date ? "Invalid Birthdate" : undefined}
          {...register("date", {
            required: true,
          })}
        />
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

After setDate is triggered, it will get a formatted string from the Date and that dateString variable is used as the value of the input. However react-hook-form doesn't seem to acknowledge the value there. I have to submit the form twice before it gets the value.
I have an example in Codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/2vwvkc
I've tried calling dispatchEvent to manually trigger the onChange on the input, similar to:
const handleDateSelect = (date: Date | undefined) => {
  setDate(date);

  const event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
  console.log(ref.current);
  ref.current.dispatchEvent(event);
  console.log('dispatched');
};

However the value is only recognized after the second form submit.
I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong but I think it has to do with how I'm updating the date in the state and then creating the dateString which is used as the value for the input.

You might wanna look into setValue. Since onChange handler is exposed by register to use for the <input> elements, in your case, you set the date based on the button click.
